# Python - Using timeout while printing line by line in a subprocess with Popen

Tags: python-3.x, timeout, subprocess, stdout

(in Python 3.5)

I am having difficulties to print stdout line by line (while running the program), and maintain the timeout function (to stop the program after sometime).

I have:

```
import subprocess as sub
import io

file_name = 'program.exe'
dir_path = r'C:/directory/'

p = sub.Popen(file_name, cwd = dir_path, shell=True, stdout = sub.PIPE, stderr = sub.STDOUT)
```

And while running "p", do these 2 things:

```
for line in io.TextIOWrapper(p.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
   print(line)
```

And do:

```
try:
    outs = p.communicate(timeout=15)   # Just to use timeout

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    p.kill()
```

The program should print every output line but should not run the simulation for more than 15 seconds.

If I use the "p.communicate" before the "p.stdout", it will wait for the timeout ou the program to finish. If I use it on the other way, the program will not count the timeout.

I would like to do it without threading, and if possible without io too, it seems to be possible, but I don´t know how (need more practice and study).  :-(

PS: The program I am running was written in fortran and is used to simulate water flow. If I run the exe from windows, it opens a cmd and prints a line on each timestep. And I am doing a sensitivity analysis changing the inputs on exe file.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your process\child processes are not getting killed correctly 
just modify your try,except as below

```
try:
    pid_id=p.pid
    outs = p.communicate(timeout=15)   # Just to use timeout


except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    import subprocesss
    #This will kill all the process and child process associated with p forcefully 
    subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /T /PID %i' % pid_id)
```